# Why is this jQuery function not communicating properly with my php file?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

Let me show you what I have:

(1) Form:

```
 <form name="login-form" class="login-form" method="post" onSubmit="login()">

  <div class="header">
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <input type="hidden" name="siteToken" value="$token" />
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="input username"  placeholder="Username" required="required" />

  <div class="user-icon"></div>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />

  <div class="pass-icon"></div>

  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
  </div>
</form>
```

(2) jQuery Function:

```
$(document).ready(function login() {
  $('.login-form').submit(function() {
      var formData = $(this).serialize();
      $("input").prop("disabled", true);
      $.post('VRC_LoginProcess.php', formData, loginMessage);

      function loginMessage(data) {
        $('.header').append(data);
      };    
  });
});
```

(3) PHP Function:

```
<?php

require_once('VRC_Header.php');
require_once('../Classes/VRC_MasterOO.php');
require_once('../Classes/VRC_Secure_Login.php');


//*******************************//
//Declerations

$signIn = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$success = "";
$error = "";

//******************************//

//****************************************************************************************//
//Script Header

$signIn = new UserService($dbuser, $dbpass, $dbhost, $dbname); //Create new class instance 
$signIn->sec_session_start(); //Begin session

//***************************************************************************************//

//***************************************************************************************//
//Begin Login Functions

if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {

    //Assign POST submissions to passable php variables
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $passedToken = $_POST['siteToken'];

    /*//Check Token Values (prevent CSRF attacks)
    if($passedToken != $_SESSION['token']) {
        $error = "CSRF attack detected. Please close your browser and try again."; 
        $signIn->csrfAttackLog($username);
        echo $error;
        exit();     
    }*/


    //Test if both fields are not null
    if($username == "" || $password == "")
    {
        $error = "Not all fields were entered<br />";
        echo $error;
        exit();
    }

    //Start login process
    else
    {
        $success = $signIn->login($username, $password);
        if ($success === true)
        { //Login Successful
            echo "Success!"; //Direct to main page.
            exit();
        }
        //Specific login failure determination
        else 
        {
            switch ($success){
                case 1:
                    $error = "Your account has been locked.";
                    echo $error;
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    $error = "Invalid Username/Password (2)";
                    echo $error;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $error = "Invalid Username/Password";
                    echo $error;
                    break;  
                case 4: 
                    $error = "Invalid Username/Password (3)";
                    echo $error;
                    break;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

?>

Fist off, I doubt the problem is in the PHP function. I've tested it before implementing jQuery calls (I used it directly in the html `action` attribute). My suspicion is that the problem is occurring in the jQuery function (I just started using jQuery and am not really familiar with it).

Note that I have removed the token input for the time being in the php file. I simply want to get it working before I deal with that (there is another problem with that part).

I don't believe that the post variables are being sent to the php file correctly. Also, I don't believe my jQuery function as it is is properly receiving the `echo` response from my php function either, in the sense that it will display it as html - provided that it worked to begin with.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: What is `formData`? Use `console.log()`.

Comment: formData is just a variable that is set equal to the url string containing the post data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly Changed your HTML to this

```
<form name="login-form" class="login-form" method="post">
    <div class="header">
         <h1>Sign In</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <input type="hidden" name="siteToken" value="$token" />
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        <div class="user-icon"></div>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <div class="pass-icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.login-form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $("input").prop("disabled", true);
        $.post('VRC_LoginProcess.php', formData, loginMessage);

        function loginMessage(data) {
            $('.header').append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, that worked, but why? It looks like the only thing you added was `function (e) { e.prevenDefault();` What exactly does that do in the case?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` prevents the default action from being performed. In case of clicking a submit-button, it will prevent the form from being submitted in the normal way (in your case sending the form data to the page itself in a post-request). This allows your javascript to properly run.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Nice, thanks for your input. I completely forgot that I had removed `onSubmit`, so it was posting it to itself like you said. Well, all works now. By the way, does my php page have to be in the same directory for this to work properly? I found if it isn't, I get a cross-origin error.

Comment: I believe, you only get a cross-origin error if you try to retrieve a page `a.example.com/page.php` via ajax from `example.com/someotherpage.php` or `b.example.com/someotherpage.php`. I don't think it should be a problem if it is in a subdirectory, unless your rewrite rules make it appear in a subdomain.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function login() {
```

That line is the problem.

Probably the login function is not available to rest of the page. It's just a name given to anonymous function which is parameter to `$(document).ready` function.

You have a scope problem.

Move the login function out separately:

```
function loginMessage(data) {
    $('.header').append(data);
};
function login() {
    $('.login-form').submit(function () {
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $("input").prop("disabled", true);
        $.post('VRC_LoginProcess.php', formData, loginMessage);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    login();
});
```

**EDIT:**

in your login function, you are registering a handler to your login form's submit event. And it has to be registered only once.

```
So, remove `onsubmit=login()` from your form's attributes, and you are good.
```

Comment: I have used just .append("something") in this function, and when I submit the form it does as it designed to do. I believe that the rest of the page is seeing the function.

Comment: Oh I might be wrong then. But, give the above code a try though.

Comment: I just did. The post is still not going through - I purposely gave it a bad password, and it wasn't logged in my database.

Comment: The `$(document).ready( );` part is unneeded here. The function should only be called when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Prasanth Well, I got an odd console error with this code: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded." I haven't seen that one before. It occurs after the function () { login();...

Comment: Also: The `loginMessage` function has to be moved out of the `login` function, or it should be made into an anonymous function in `$.post`'s 3rd argument.

Comment: @Prasanth I don't understand why this is not working. I even changed my php file to something as simple as `echo "test"` and I still don't get a response back.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Why must the `loginMessage` be moved outside of the `login` function? I've seen plenty of examples where it's been inside another function like this one.

Comment: Well, no luck there. But Atif's jQuery function below works. And I don't know why...